# How to cut corner from rounded shape?

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

How can I create this custom shape in a way that can contain text, using CSS?

[image: CSS rounded shape cut corner]

I designed it in illustrator, and when I export this as a "svg", the svg code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="258.3px" height="47.6px" viewBox="0 0 258.3 47.6" enable-background="new 0 0 258.3 47.6" xml:space="preserve">
</svg>
```

But it's not working in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a single gradient :

```css
.notch {
  width: 258.3px;
  height: 47.6px;
  border-radius: 30px 0 0;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,transparent 12px , #8DC73F 12px);
}
body {
  background:rgb(93, 93, 93)
}
```

```html
<div class="notch"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a shape with a single curved border, and then create the notch by using a pseudoelement.

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40px 0 0;
  background: #8DC73F;
  position: relative;
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the `linear-gradient` solution but here is another way using `clip-path`:

```css
.notch {
  width: 258.3px;
  height: 47.6px;
  border-radius: 30px 0 0;
  background: #8DC73F;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 10% 100%, 0 64%);
}

body {
  background: rgb(93, 93, 93)
}
```

```html
<div class="notch"></div>
```